# touchesBegan and touchesMoved not getting triggered on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, touchesbegan

## What I'm trying to achieve:

Trying to grab the coordinate of the currently touched area on the screen and draw the received coordinate on the screen. Simply put, a basic drawing app that's all written programmatically (for my own practice).

## Problem

`touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` for `PaintingSubclass` are not getting called at all.

## Current setup

- I have a `PaintingViewController` then I also have a `PaintingSubclass`.
- `PaintingViewController` is a `UIViewController` and `PaintingSubclass` is a `UIView`.
- `PaintingViewController` creates an instance of `PaintingSubclass` and adds it to the **subview** of `PaintingViewController`.
- `PaintingSubclass` is where the actual drawing happens.

## What I've tried so far

- Put a breakpoint inside the `touchesMoved` and touchesBegan **(didn't work)**
- Tried to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` **(didn't work)**
- Enabled `self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` **(didn't work)**
- Make `PaintingSubclass` inherit `UIControl` and call `sendActions(for: .valueChanged)` at the end of `touchesMoved` and `touchesBegan` **(didn't work)**

## Current Code

(please ignore any the unnecessary variables)

```
import UIKit

class PaintingViewController: UIViewController{

var _paintView: PaintingSubclass? = nil

override func loadView() {
    view = UILabel()
}

private var labelView: UILabel {
    return view as! UILabel
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    _paintView = PaintingSubclass()
    _paintView?.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.minX, y: view.bounds.minY, width: 400, height: 750)
    _paintView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    _paintView?.setNeedsDisplay()

    view.addSubview(_paintView!)
}

class PaintingSubclass: UIView{

    private var context: CGContext? = nil
    var styleSelection: String = "buttcap"
    var linewidth: Float = 5
    var lineCapStyle: CGLineCap? = nil
    var lineJoinStyle: CGLineJoin? = nil
    var lineWidthValue: CGFloat? = nil
    var colorValue: UIColor? = nil

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        lineWidthValue = 0.5
        colorValue = UIColor(cgColor: UIColor.black.cgColor)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 110.0))
        context?.setStrokeColor((colorValue?.cgColor)!)
        context?.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.stroke)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
        let touchPoint: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)

        let _xValue = touchPoint.x
        let _yValue = touchPoint.y

        NSLog("coordinate: \(_xValue), \(_yValue)")
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

        let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
        let touchPoint: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)

        let _xValue = touchPoint.x
        let _yValue = touchPoint.y

        NSLog("coordinate: \(_xValue), \(_yValue)")
    }   
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Been stuck in this state for hours not making any progress. Any help/feedbacks will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried checking its privilege? That usually gets things pretty triggered in my experience

Comment: `view = UILabel()` What does this line explaining?

Comment: Can you add your UI images?

Comment: can you set    flexibleWidth and flexibleHeight of autoresizingMask   to subclass view..then add  super.init(coder: aDecoder)

Comment: Problem was a very simple one... I just had to enable isUserInteractionEnabled to true on the VIEW not self. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are setting your default view to `UILabel()`, but your default `isUserInteractionEnabled` of your `view` is false. Set it to true

```
override func loadView() {
    view = UILabel()
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: isUerInteractionEnabled was one of the first thing I tried, but turns out I had to enable this on the view not self (which I thought it would be the same for some reason). It was late at night.. ;)

Comment: That's great :)

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, your PaintingViewController's view is a UILabel, the property `isUserInteractionEnabled` default is false.Try to set this property to true may help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on:

```
//    override func loadView() {
//        view = UILabel()
//    }
//    
//    private var labelView: UILabel {
//        return view as! UILabel
//    }
```

You turn the view controller's self view object to a UILabel object.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have your painting view as the main view in the view controller and the UILabel as a subview of the painting view. The UILabel needs to have userInteractionEnabled in your current layout, but instead of changing that switch the layout around.

Apart from anything else, presumably you don't want the painting view to draw over the label, but rather the label to be drawn on top, so the label should be the subview.

Comment: The only reason I have the PaintingViewController as the main class, is because this view gets called from a pushViewController from another screen and I haven't found a way to push to a new UIView using pushViewController.